# R: Warning: get NA when I try to use my function

Tags: r, function, vector, na

I am brand new to programming and am trying to write a function in R that calculates the mean of a pollutant (nitrate or sulfate) across a specified list of monitors (each monitor has its own .csv file in the folder "specdata"). I have constructed the following function:

```
pollutantmean <- function(directory="specdata", pollutant="sulfate", id=1:332)
{
    files_f<-list.files(directory,full.names=TRUE)
    d <- data.frame()

    for(i in 1:332){ 
        d <- rbind(d,read.csv(files_f[i])) 
    }
    if(pollutant=="sulfate"){ 
        mean(d$Sulfate[which(d$ID==id)], na.rm=TRUE) 
    }
    else{ 
        mean(d$Nitrate[which(d$ID==id)], na.rm=TRUE) 
    }
}
```

And then I tried to test the function with:
    `pollutantmean(directory="specdata",pollutant="sulfate", id=1:10)`

I then get the following error:

```
[1] NA Warning messages:
1: In d$ID == id :
longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
2: In mean.default(d$Sulfate[which(d$ID == id)], na.rm = TRUE) :
argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
```

What does this mean? I've gone through my code many times but can't identify what the problem is.

Thank you.

Comment: (1) your code is "reaching outside its scope" by referencing `files_f[i]`, this scope violation should be avoided; (2) you have `1:332` hard-coded in both `id` and in your `for` loop, is that intentional?; (3) your problem is because you are comparing two vectors of different lengths, both greater than 1. What do you propose the result should be in `1:4 == 1:3`? (It's clear to say `1:4 == 1` and `1 == 1:3`, but not both sides being vectors.)

Comment: (4) [This Coursera topic has been asked to death](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Br%5D+pollutantmean)

Comment: rich...you beat me to the #4 your cheating on homework post!

Comment: @r2evans Thank you for the response. (1) Why is it reaching outside its scope?  There are 332 files that I wish to put together in a data frame, and I'm asking R to add files 1 through 332 to the loop... wouldn't there only be an issue if I used 1:n where n>332? (2) Why would 1:332 be hard-coded? I thought that by putting id=1:332 in the first line I was just defining a default range that could be replaced if desired (e.g. with 1:10). (3) I don't understand this comment. What two vectors are creating the problem?

Comment: I think you should replace `which(d$ID==id)` with `which(d$ID %in% id)`, otherwise you end up testing the equality of `d$ID` and `id`, which are unequal length vectors.

Comment: (1) where is `files_f` defined? If not inside the function or as a function argument, it's out of scope (few exceptions); (2) you can use `1:length(files_f)`, with or without fixing scope; (3) both `df$ID` and `id` are vectors both with lengths great than 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here I think I've implemented the suggestions in the comments, shortened the code, and even generalized the function in case you ever want to investigate other pollutants (just be sure to spell them the same as in the csv's, including capitalization):

```
   pollutantmean <- function(directory="specdata", 
                              pollutant="Sulfate", 
                              id=1:332){
      files_f <- list.files(directory,full.names=TRUE)
      d <- do.call(rbind, lapply(files_f, read.csv, stringsAsFactors=FALSE))
      mean(d[[pollutant]][which(d$ID %in% id)], na.rm=TRUE)
    }
```

Hope that works, good luck with the pollutant monitoring

Comment: You could further simplify the code by replacing the `d <- data.frame()/for` with `d <- do.call(rbind, lapply(files_f, read.csv))`.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I tried your code and got [1]NA and the error "Warning message:
In mean.default(d[[pollutant]][which(d$ID %in% id)], na.rm = TRUE) :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA"-- I don't understand why the argument is not considered numeric. Any thoughts? Is it a problem with d$ID or id? @RuiBarradas I also get the same error message when I sub in your recommended code.

Comment: @Jab: It may be a problem with `d$ID`, it may be of class `factor`. But as far as I can see, my code is equivalent to AlexP's. A way of telling is to include a `print(class(d$ID))` statement before the `mean(...)` instruction.